# How to break out of read_loop() in python-evdev?

Tags: python-3.x, evdev

I am using read_loop() from python-evdev to capture the codes from an ir remote control.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from evdev import InputDevice
dev = InputDevice('/dev/input/event0')
for event in dev.read_loop():
    print(event.value)
```

How can I break out of the loop when the codes from a button are received and the button no longer is pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reckon `read_loop` results in an endless loop. If you are looking to read a single input event, `read_one` would be the better choice.

Source: [Page 25](https://readthedocs.org/projects/python-evdev/downloads/pdf/latest/)